# ¿Cómo se usan las variables en Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, imprimir

Estoy intentando programar una macro para imprimir un área seleccionada de excel cada que cambia el valor de dos celdas; la primera es el concepto que cambia de acuerdo a una lista de manera vertical mientras que para las cantidades hay una serie de cantidades que cambian de manera horizontal.

Cada que se aplique la macro, las cantidades se cambian a lo largo de una fila que se encuentra definida como "dia"
Intenté cambiar el tipo de variable, ya que luego de introducir los valores la macro se deja de correr

Pero debido a que no sé mucho de VBA, no sé cual otro error esté cometiendo

```
`Sub Imprimir()
'
' Imprimir Macro
'
' Acceso directo: CTRL+i
'
'Datos a insertar
Dim lim_inferior As Integer
Dim lim_superior  As Integer
Dim dia As Integer
Dim preg_concepto As Integer
Dim concepto As Integer

lim_inferior = InputBox(prompt:="Dame el número de la primera nota 
que quieres imprimir")
lim_superior = InputBox(prompt:="Dame el número de la última nota 
que quieres imprimir")
dia = InputBox(prompt:="¿Qué día estás imprimiendo?")
concepto = InputBox(prompt:="¿El último concepto fue 'Cerraduras 
tornillos y llaves'? (1, para sí y 0, para no)")

'Procedimiento
If concepto = 0 Then
concepto = InputBox(prompt:="¿En cuál concepto te quedaste?")
End If

lim_inferior = lim_inferior + 2
lim_superior = lim_superior + 2
concepto = 20
dia = dia + 20

For l_i = lim_inferior To l_s = lim_superior
' Cantidad
Range("AZ124").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[dia]C[l_i]"
' Concepto
Range("AV124").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[concepto]C[-4]"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    
    If concepto = 47 Then
    concepto = 20
    End If
    concepto = concepto + 1
Next

End Sub`
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia ahora mismo. Deberías enfocar la pregunta, y abrir varias si es necesario. Es mejor que postees varias separadas, que 1 sola con todo. Respecto a tu código, por ejemplo `"=R[concepto]C[-4]"` está mal. Si quieres usar el valor almacenado en la variable `concepto` tendría que ser `"=R[" & concepto & "]C[-4]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La macro parece dejar de correr puesto que se salta el loop For debido a que está mal declarada la condición de finalización.

Debería ser:

```
For l_i = lim_inferior To lim_superior
```

ya que la variable `lim_superior` no va a sufrir modificaciones por lo que veo de tu código.
En caso de que deba cambiar en un futuro declara `l_s = lim_superior` antes del For.

Ejemplo:

```
l_s = lim_superior
For l_i = lim_inferior To l_s
```

Adicional tienes algunos detallitos como que estás preguntando al usuario por un valor "concepto" que de todos modos modificas 3 líneas después a 20.

Por último recuerda que las fórmulas que va a imprimir tu macro en las celdas van entre comillas pero si vas a meter el valor de una variable de tu código necesitas agregarla de la siguiente forma:

```
"=formula" & variable & "resto de la formula"
```

Ejemplo:

```
"=R[concepto]C[-4]"  debe ser --> "=R[" & concepto & "]C[-4]"
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Alex tenía razón, actualicé la condición del ciclo For, pero además me fue más efectivo hacer uso de Offset para sustituir el valor en la celda que necesitaba.

```
Sub Imprimir()
'
' Imprimir Macro
'
' Acceso directo: CTRL+i
'
'Datos a insertar
Dim lim_inferior As Integer
Dim lim_superior  As Integer
Dim dia As Integer
Dim preg_concepto As Integer
Dim concepto As Integer

lim_inferior = InputBox(prompt:="Dame el número de la primera nota que quieres 
imprimir")
lim_superior = InputBox(prompt:="Dame el número de la última nota que quieres 
imprimir")
dia = InputBox(prompt:="¿Qué día estás imprimiendo?")
concepto = MsgBox("¿El último concepto fue 'Cerraduras tornillos y llaves'?", vbYesNo 
+ vbQuestion, "Concepto")

'Procedimiento
If concepto = vbNo Then
concepto = InputBox(prompt:="¿En cuál concepto te quedaste?")
concepto = concepto + 144
Else
concepto = 144
End If

lim_inferior = lim_inferior + 1
lim_superior = lim_superior + 1
dia = dia + 20

For l_i = lim_inferior To lim_superior
' Cantidad
Range("AZ124").Select
ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(dia, l_i)
' Concepto
Range("AV124").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=AR" & concepto
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    
    If concepto = 170 Then
    concepto = 144
    End If
    concepto = concepto + 1
Next

End Sub
```

De igual manera gracias, la próxima ocasión trataré de ser más clara y específica con mi pregunta